# Should a switch statement be used this way?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Is it acceptable to use a `switch` as a way of supporting multiple file formats, or is it bad practice?

Like so (untested):

```
<?php

    // Load file
    switch ($data_format) {
        case 'xml':
            $openfile = simplexml_load_file($filename . '.xml');
            break;

        case 'json':
            $openfile = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename . '.json'));
            break;
    }

    // Do stuff

    // Save file
    switch ($data_format) {
        case 'xml':
            $openfile->asXML($filename . '.xml');
            break;

        case 'json':
            file_put_contents($filename . '.json', json_encode($openfile, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            break;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your style of coding. If you want to work object oriented then this would be against the idea. In this case you'd use something like:

```php
$file = $repository->open($filename, $data_format);
// do stuff
$file->save();
```

Of course `$repository->open()` needs to return an object with a different save method depending on your data format.

However if you are not working object oriented but good old procedural style I cannot see anything wrong with your use of the switch statement.

Comment: Wouldn't the `open` method here have to have some kind of code like a switch to open the different data files, or multiple methods for each data format? Would something like this be acceptable `$file = $repository->{$data_format}_open($filename);` ?

Comment: Since $data_format is a string in your case you will need to perform a switch (or if/else or map lookup) at some point. The advantage of the Object oriented approach is that you need no more then a single switch (your approach needs it twice) and you separate the concern of deciding how to load/save from whatever you do with your file which can improve readability and testability.

Comment: @Coffee'dUpHacker: Your proposal `$repository->{$data_format}_open($filename);` would of course work, but in my opinion it hurts the readability because it is not entirely clear which values `$data_format` may have in the moment of calling.